# Mongo query to be written to spring data query for aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I want to use below query with spring data mongoDB :

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {"$sort": {"contactInfo.version": -1}},
    {$group:{_id:"$contactInfo.contact", "maxValue": {$max:"$contactInfo.version"}, "userAgg": { "$first": "$$CURRENT" }}},
    { $project : { "userAgg" : 1 ,_id : 0 }}
]);
```

We have user data like this :

```
{
            "contactInfo": {
                "version": "00",
                "contact": "1234567890",
                "addressLine1": "Street Number 1",
                "addressLine2": "Newyork",
                "addressLine3": "US"
            },
            "name": "John Smith",
            "department": "IT",
            "skill": "Java",
            "experience": "4",
            "workStatus": "Project"
       }
```

I am doing aggregation like below but getting null

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
     sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "contactInfo.version"),
     group("contactInfo.contact","contactInfo.version").max("contactInfo.version").as("userCurrentInfo").first("$$CURRENT").as("userAggregate"),
     project("userAggregate")
    );
    AggregationResults<UserAggregate> groupResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, "userDB", UserAggregate.class);
    List<UserAggregate> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

Can anybody help me getting the user data for max version, for the above query in spring data mongoDB.
Added UserAggregation pojo, how it looks like, since my query is returning me data like

```
 {
         "userAgg" : {
            "contactInfo": {
                "version": "00",
                "contact": "1234567890",
                "addressLine1": "Street Number 1",
                "addressLine2": "Newyork",
                "addressLine3": "US"
            },
            "name": "John Smith",
            "department": "IT",
            "skill": "Java",
            "experience": "4",
            "workStatus": "Project"
         }
       }

public class UserAggregation
{
  UserAgg userAgg;
}

public class UserAgg
{
  User user;
}
```

Comment: It looks like mapping to pojo not working. Can you add `UserAggregate` pojo to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram added the UserAggregate  pojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having null value because there is no field as `user` in your aggregation response.

Assuming your `User` pojo is correctly set up you can try below aggregation, you can update your project to adjust to your pojo hierarchy i.e map `("userAgg").as("userAgg.user")`

```
 Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
   sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "contactInfo.version"),           
   group("contactInfo.contact","contactInfo.version").
       max("contactInfo.version").as("userCurrentInfo").first("$$CURRENT").as("userAgg"),
   project().and("userAgg").as("userAgg.user")
 );

 List<UserAggregate> groupResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, "userDB", UserAggregate.class).getMappedResults();
```

Refactor Version:

You can update quite a few things here, like removing the `UserAggregate`, `UserAgg` pojo and map directly to `User` and simplify aggregation query to remove `max` operator, `contactInfo.version` grouping key and use only `$first` with `$$ROOT` to get the max versioned document on the sorted data.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
      sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "contactInfo.version"),
      group("contactInfo.contact").first("$$ROOT").as("user"),
      project("user").andExclude("_id")
 );

List<User> groupResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, User.class, User.class).getMappedResults();
```